# Round (floor) to the nearest member of the geometric sequence (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 . . . )?

Tags: python

As the title explains, how could I create a function `func` (using numpy or math modules) to find the nearest member of the geometric sequence (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 . . . )?

For example, `func(3)` should yield 2, `func(20)` should yield 16, and `func(128)` should yield 128.

I cannot find any information on this problem. Most rounding problems discuss rounding to the nearest multiple of some number, rather than to the nearest member of a geometric sequence.

Comment: Just this specific sequence, or any general geometric sequence?

Comment: There is information about this problem, but it's typically called "round down to power of 2" (commonly solutions are built around `bit_length`) and it's more common to want to round *up* but that's a small modification away from rounding down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the concept of power and log

```
import numpy as np
def round_to_geometric(x):
    return int(2 ** np.floor(np.log2(x)))
```

output:

```
> print(round_to_geometric(3))
> print(round_to_geometric(20))
> print(round_to_geometric(128))

2
16
128
```

Comment: `from math import log, floor` and `int(2 ** floor(log(x, 2)))` is an alternative if `numpy` is unavailable.

Comment: yes, totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about this is in terms of the length of a binary representation of an integer:

```py
def myround(i):
  return 2 ** (len(bin(i)) - 3)
```

```py
>>> [myround(i) for i in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 25, 128)]
[2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 16, 16, 128]
```

Explanation: `bin(x)` returns a binary string representation of the input.

```py
>>> bin(20)
'0b10100'
```

The length of this representation depends on the most significant bit in the sequence. For `bin(20)`, the most significant bit is 16 (or `2 ** 4`). Subtracting 3 ignores the `0b` and the `1s` place in the binary string. So `len(bin(20)) - 3 = 4`